# Meaning of F(E)Z(E) in semiconductor theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics

I really don't understand the following term

$$ \int F(E)Z(E)dE$$

where $F(E)$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution (but it could be any distribution) and $Z(E)$ is the density of states.

What I really don't understand is what does the multiplication $F(E)Z(E)$ mean in probabilistic terms. For what I understand:

- $F(E)$ is the probability of the state with energy $E$ to be occupied
- $Z(E)$ is the amount of states in $E$

$F(E)$ is called a *distribution* in the book I'm reading, but isn't it a probability *density*? If it is a density, integrating a density over a certain region gives the probability of the event associated with that region happening, but what would it mean to multiply the denisty by another function when integrating?

Comment: $F(E)$ is no probability density, this can easily be seen, for example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dE\,F(E) \ne 1$.

Comment: If you take the integral over the conduction (or valance) band, you will get the number of electrons in that band...